# Nuget Package Manager not installing correct version of Ubiety.Dns.Core

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I have specified in Visual Studio to use version 4.2.2 of Ubiety.Dns.Core:
[image]

But when built, it places version 2.2.1 in the bin folder:
[image]

This is an archaic version that will not run on Windows Server. Is there anyway to make this behave properly?
In the meantime I take taken to manually replacing it with the correct dll.

Comment: Have you checked that the DLL is not accidentally overwritten with the older version during build? Like from a transitive dependency or build script

Answer (score 0):

Researching other answers had lead me to believe that this was being managed in my Web.config, but after much searching I found that the issue was actually in my .csproj:

`<Reference Include="Ubiety.Dns.Core, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL">`

After deleting that section, a reinstall of the package finally caused it to be  installed correctly.